# How to arrange floating elements vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I have 3 fieldsets.

What I would like to make is this layout:[image]

I want the bottom right fieldset to be bottom aligned, so it's bottom would be aligned with the left fieldset.

It should work in different resolutions.

Is there an easy way? or I will have to use javascript to add to it a margin-top dynamically?

code:

```
<div class="fieldSetsContainer">
<fieldset class="leftFieldSet">test
    <br/>test
    <br/>test
    <br/>test
    <br/>test
    <br/>test
    <br/>
</fieldset>
<div class="rightFieldSets">
    <fieldset>test2</fieldset>
    <fieldset class="bottomRightFieldSet">test3</fieldset>
</div>
```

css:

```
.rightFieldSets {
float:left;
width:34%;
}
.rightFieldSets fieldset {
clear:left;
width:89%;
}
.leftFieldSet {
width:62%;
float:left;
margin-right:1px;
}
.bottomRightFieldSet {
margin-top:6px;
}
```

here is the a link:
http://jsfiddle.net/bbryK/

Comment: what are the constraints for the divs? Are the widths constants or fluid? can the height of two right divs be higher than left div?

Comment: can u share a fiddle link

Comment: I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bbryK/1/

Comment: Thinking about it, it would be the best if I can define the heights of the 2 right fieldsets in percentage and support cases of each column shorter than the other and then the shorter column height would be set as the max height. But I can also be satisfied with assuming the left column always higher and then I need the right bottom column to be aligned to bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution assumes two things:

- The right column has a fixed width.
- The left column must always be the highest.

See http://jsfiddle.net/c3AFP/2/

Html structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">
        <fieldset class="top"></fieldset>
        <fieldset class="bottom"></fieldset>
    </div>
    <fieldset class="left"></fieldset>
</div>
```

Css styles:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.top, .bottom {
    width: 300px;
}
.left {
    margin-right: 300px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a solution with the right column sized by percentage: http://jsfiddle.net/c3AFP/5/

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a table based solution which removes the requirement of the left column being the tallest. Using `vertical-align` you can adjust where the smaller elements should align in relation to the tallest one: http://jsfiddle.net/c3AFP/7/

Comment: Thanks, that is the closest solution. However Can't it be improved so you don't have to define a fixed width to the right column? The rational behind it is to support multiple screen resolutions. And preferably window resizing.

Comment: Added a solution with variable sized right column, but now as I think about it: Why don't you use a table? That should also remove the requirement of the left column being the tallest.

Comment: Added a table based solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving you a start point on fiddle. Please play around, make some code and do share the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/vY462/

```
#one{width:200px;height:70px;border:2px solid black;float:left;}
#two,#three{width:200px;height:25px;border:2px solid black;float:right;margin-top:5px;}

<div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div>
<div id="three">3</div>
```

Comment: how does this work for different font-sizes, which is the requirement here i believe?

Comment: You have not mentioned font-size requirements anywhere. Please mention the same.

Comment: There is no font-size requirement here, if it matters, but the content of the fieldsets is not constant.

Comment: So, you want the height of div to grow or shrink with content?

Comment: Exactly, height of div or fieldsets is not known, it should be fit to their content.

Comment: So, you don't need to specify height.